# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality of expectation values of operators

Tags: density-matrix

For two operators $A, B$ defined on Hibert space $H_n$, the state is $\rho$, then there is

$$\langle AB \rangle +\sqrt{\langle A \rangle - (\langle A \rangle)^2}\sqrt{\langle B \rangle - (\langle B \rangle)^2} \geq \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle$$

In the derivation of (23) in the following paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.2024), it was claimed to be one form of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on expectation values of operators, but I failed to see why it is true.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing you're missing a squared inside the square roots? if you have $\langle A^2\rangle-\langle A\rangle^2$ in there (and same for $B$) this is essentially Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson%E2%80%93Schr%C3%B6dinger_uncertainty_relations. Also, what is "it" here? Can you edit the post to link to the source?

Comment: @glS Thanks for the reply. In the original derivation, it is indeed $\langle A \rangle$. I attach the source link in the edited question.

Comment: it's not super obvious from that equation in the paper. Maybe $A,B$ are projections, and therefore $A=A^2$?

Comment: @glS A and B are projectors.

Answer (score 1):

I think the inequality you gave
$$\tag{1} \langle AB \rangle +\sqrt{\langle A \rangle - (\langle A \rangle)^2}\sqrt{\langle B \rangle - (\langle B \rangle)^2} \geq \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle$$
makes no sense in general.

Take $n=2$, $A=2I$, $B=\frac{1}{2}I$ and let $\rho$ be a maximally mixed state, i.e. $\rho = \frac{1}{2}I$.
Then $\sqrt{\langle A \rangle - \langle A \rangle^2} = \sqrt{-2}$ is a complex number, and $\sqrt{\langle B \rangle - \langle B \rangle^2}$ is a real number. Hence, the LHS of Eq (1) is a complex number. Essentially, the inequality attempts to compare a complex number on the LHS with a real number on RHS.

For this to make sense, much stronger assumptions may be needed.

Comment: while true, the closely related inequality $\sqrt{\langle A^2\rangle-\langle A\rangle^2} \sqrt{\langle B^2\rangle-\langle B\rangle^2} \ge |\langle A  B\rangle - \langle A\rangle \langle B \rangle|$ does indeed hold, and is nothing but Heisenberg's uncertainty principle in a slightly more general form. Well, it holds for pure states at least, and it's a direct application of CS there. Essentially $\langle \psi,AB \psi\rangle|^2\le \|A \psi\|^2 \|B\psi\|^2$ with suitably chosen operators $A,B$ and with $\psi$ the pure state.

Comment: the given equation might reduce to this if, say, $A,B$ are projectors, and the state pure, and for some reason $\langle AB\rangle \le  \langle A\rangle \langle B\rangle$. Note that in such scenarios $\langle A\rangle\ge \langle A\rangle^2$ so the square roots can be safely assumed to be real

Comment: @glS ah interesting! Thanks! What do I google to see the proof of that?